# while loop doesnt work, javascript only

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop

I want to move this red rectangle randomly over the screen and if I click on it,  it should fall down. I need this code in javascript only , no jQuery, please.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1280" height="600" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;color:red;"></canvas>
        <p>the main purpose of this code is i need to move this div randomlly and if i click on it it will fall down ,
                i need this code in javascript only , no jquery,please help</p>
    <script>   
            var i = 0 ;
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            //var f = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*1280)
            //var f2 = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*600)
            //ctx.translate(f, f2);
            //ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 50);
        var s = true;
        while(s = true){
            var f = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*1280);
            var f2 = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*600);
            ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
            ctx.translate(f, f2);
            ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 50); 
            var w = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                w.onclick = true;
            if (w.onclick = true){
                s = false;falling();}
            else(){continue;}}
        function falling(){
            s = false;
        }              
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `=` is not a comparison operator. Use `==`.
`while(s == true){`
`if (w.onclick == true){`

Comment: Nothing bro ,need help

Comment: Delete `()` after `else`.
But your code seems infinity loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your code, both syntactic and logically:

1. `else()` else is not a function
2. `while(s = true)` see the comment by @yasuyuki-uno
3. you are declaring `var i` without using it

Then you have an infinite loop that is so fast that the browser locks up. You need to use `setInterval()` instead.

A fixed version looks like this:

```
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var w = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  timer = setInterval(function() { 

        var f = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*680);
        var f2 = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*400);
      console.log (f, f2);

        ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        ctx.fillRect(f, f2, 100, 50); 
        w.onclick = function() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            falling();
        } 
     }, 100)
    function falling(){
       // do something here
    }
```

See also [the JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hitapimase/1/edit?html,output).

But please, before coming with code containing syntax errors, go to something like http://www.jslint.com/ and check your code first.

Comment: Thank you man a lot , but how can I add transition duration to the canvas ?
I'm so new in coding

Comment: That should be a new question with a `canvas` tag

Comment: I'm sorry man , I mean between evey position of the canvas I need like
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;

Comment: I know. But Stackoverflow really works like "one problem per question". So if you need transitions, ask a new question.